# Java HTTP proxy: get hostname for connection

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I am making a small time local HTTP proxy that should be a middle man for a browser and webservers. I am in a way doing what Burp Suite is doing.

To make the HTTP traffic to go throu the program I put these settings into the network setting in the browser-->
Use proxy
127.0.0.1
port 8080

The program is able to connect with the browser and

```
System.out.println
```

the information is printed like so

```
CONNECT location.services.mozilla.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: location.services.mozilla.com:443
```

So I know the program recieves the right information.

To connect to the webserver I use the hostname in the information above.

```
Socket webserverConnection = new Socket(this.hostname, this.port);//host is location.services.mozilla.com
                                                                  //port is 443
```

The way I parse for the host I do

```
int start = browserRequest.indexOf("Host: ") + 6;
            int end = browserRequest.indexOf(':', start) + 1;
            this.hostname = browserRequest.substring(start, end - 1);
```

However some times I get this error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: detectportal.firefox.com
User-Agent
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:520)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:294)
    at ConnectionHandling.run(ConnectionHandling.java:49)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

How do correctly I get the hostname?

Comment: I think the proxy gets the hostname correctly. The detectportal.firefox.com is used by firefox to detect wifi portals that try to captivate your traffic inject their login screen (free wifi in hotels and so on). You can turn it off with set "network.captive-portal-service.enabled" to false.

Comment: Ah okey. That clarifies somewhat my situation.